# VSTS GIT REST API ignores the "ExcludeDeletes"; is there a workaround?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm experiencing an issue which seems to point to the VSTS REST API for Git not working properly in an edge case scenario. My goal is to verify that a commit has been removed from VSTS via a rebase squash; I have the projectId, repositoryId and commit hash available, and the API presents a trivial way of doing this - or so I think - via setting the "ExcludeDeletes" parameter when retrieving the commit, yet it's not working properly for me: I still get the commit from VSTS, as if it existed.

Workflow:

1. Create a repo.
2. Create 3 commits.
3. Push to remote.
4. Rebase-squash 2nd commit by doing the interactive rebase --onto
5. Force push to remote (may need to set permission for that first)
6. Observe commit absent locally via "git log | grep "
7. Perform the VSTS Api request by ProjectId, RepositoryId and CommitId, using this for filter:

> ```
> new GitQueryCommitsCriteria 
> { 
>     FromCommitId = {localCommitHash.Hash},
>     ToCommitId = {localCommitHash.Hash}, 
>     ExcludeDeletes = true 
> };
> ```

8. Observe the presence of commit in the VSTS response, despite the "ExcludeDeletes" field being set to "true".

I also tried to issue the GET using Postman, for both 4.1 and 5.0-preview APIs, to no avail.

The behaviour I'm expecting from VSTS here is tied to a crucial part of business logic for the project, and I would appreciate any assistance with the matter; perhaps I misunderstand the field's intent, in which case I really could use some guidance as to how to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the deleted commits still listed even specify `excludeDeletes` option as `true` in the [REST API Get Commits Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits%20batch?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

And it seems you have already report it in [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289317/vsts-git-rest-api-returns-a-rebase-squashed-commit.html). So you can follow up there and wait for the response of the feature team.

The workaround for now to exclude the deleted commits from the response is **specifying the branch you want to get the commits from**.

Such as if you squash rebase commits on `master` branch, then you can get commits from `master` branch by the request body:

```
{
  "itemVersion": {
    "versionType": "branch",
    "version": "master"
  },
  "fromCommitId": "string",
  "toCommitId": "string",
}
```

Then the reponse exclude the deleted commits (the commits has been squashed rebase) on `master` branch by default.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Marina; I'm afraid I need all the branches - the local repo is a mirror clone, storing commits for auditing purposes - and, while I could enumerate branches, it would take an inordinate amount of time to complete. Thank you for the confirmation though; we'll go with a bypass then.